# 12.04.2 Install/reboot problem

Tags: 12.04, installation, iso, dvd, reboot

I downloaded 12.04.2 LTS and burned the iso to dvd, dropped it into the dvd drive then restarted my computer. Everything worked fine and the install process went thru without any errors *UNTIL* it got the the reboot process. After it finishes install and it then tells you that you need to reboot in order to use the new installation, I click Reboot and it runs thru the process of ending everything so it can reboot and all of the sections shown during this process all come up as "OK" result but it still "hangs" and the system never fully reboots and it just sits there.

Any idea as to why it hangs on the reboot?

Comment: I've being using 32Bit version

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you chose the 64 bit version if your computer is 64 and 32 if your computer is 32. This happened to me before the only thing that worked with me was installing ubuntu 12.10 from a usb.

Comment: Same thing was happened to me in UBUNTU 12.10 32 and 64 bit